# copy a xlsm file with buttons into another xlsm file without reassign

Tags: excel, vba

How to copy a xlsm file that has buttons into another xlsm file without having to reassign each button manually?

See unsloved post:

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/macro-assigned-to-the-button-form-control-doesnt-work-in-copied-file-with-new-name.1158556/

Comment: Please share the code that you use for copying the workbook and describe your issue in more detail.

Comment: Manually copying the sheet by "move or copy option" in Excel